# HP Switch STP configuration

Tags: networking, switch

We have multiple switches and STP enabled on all switches..
But some of the switches are flickering in who becomes the STP master..

I think there are some configuration problems.. If we look at the "main" switch and one of the others..

The main switch looks like this

```
Multiple Spanning Tree (MST) Information

  STP Enabled   : Yes
  Force Version : MSTP-operation
  IST Mapped VLANs : 1-4094
  Switch MAC Address : b05ada-2f76cb
  Switch Priority    : 0
  Max Age  : 20
  Max Hops : 20
  Forward Delay : 15

  Topology Change Count  : 8277
  Time Since Last Change : 2 mins

  CST Root MAC Address : 20677c-a64200
  CST Root Priority    : 0
  CST Root Path Cost   : 20000
  CST Root Port        : 2/46

  IST Regional Root MAC Address : b05ada-2f76cb
  IST Regional Root Priority    : 0
  IST Regional Root Path Cost   : 0
  IST Remaining Hops            : 20

  Root Guard Ports     :
  Loop Guard Ports     :
  TCN Guard Ports      :
  BPDU Protected Ports :
  BPDU Filtered Ports  : 2/31-2/32
  PVST Protected Ports :
  PVST Filtered Ports  :

  Root Inconsistent Ports  :
  Loop Inconsistent Ports  :
```

And one of the others:

```
Multiple Spanning Tree (MST) Information

  STP Enabled   : Yes
  Force Version : MSTP-operation
  IST Mapped VLANs : 1-4094
  Switch MAC Address : 941882-b26c00
  Switch Priority    : 32768
  Max Age  : 20
  Max Hops : 20
  Forward Delay : 15

  Topology Change Count  : 5
  Time Since Last Change : 54 mins

  CST Root MAC Address : 20677c-a64200
  CST Root Priority    : 0
  CST Root Path Cost   : 60000
  CST Root Port        : 24

  IST Regional Root MAC Address : 941882-b26c00
  IST Regional Root Priority    : 32768
  IST Regional Root Path Cost   : 0
  IST Remaining Hops            : 20

  Root Guard Ports     :
  Loop Guard Ports     :
  TCN Guard Ports      :
  BPDU Protected Ports :
  BPDU Filtered Ports  :
  PVST Protected Ports :
  PVST Filtered Ports  :

  Root Inconsistent Ports  :
  Loop Inconsistent Ports  :
```

What I can see is that they both have CST Root Priority set to 0? But do have different switch priority..

Also they have same "MST Configuration Revision" but different "MST Configuration Name"..

Is that correct?

Comment: Can you look at the switch 20:67:7c:a6:42:00 and check why its priority is also set to 0, if it's not the "root" switch?

Comment: hmm yes.. But we can't seem to locate that mac address in the network.. But according to basically all the switch event logs, they are switching back and forth to that mac...

Comment: It turns out they have a new switch witch was configured wrong.. The switch was not in use, so I disabled port 2/26.

Comment: To prevent an unwanted switch to grab the root you should use the `root-guard` feature - `spanning tree [n] root-guard` prevents port [n] to become the root port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I can see is that they both have CST Root Priority set to 0? But do have different switch priority..

That's normal – the "CST Root Priority" doesn't come from the switch you're looking at. It shows information about what switch is currently elected via STP to be the 'root' switch.

For example, since you have b05ada-2f76cb with priority 0, it should normally become the root switch, and all your switches should show "CST Root MAC Address: b05ada-2f76cb" along with "CST Root Priority: 0".

But in your case, you have a mysterious switch 20677c-a64200 (20:67:7c:a6:42:00) also configured with priority 0 *and* it has a numerically lower MAC address, so it's the one that gets elected as the root. (And if it frequently gets disconnected & reconnected, that'll certainly shake the whole tree.)

So track the switch down (it might not be a switch, it might be a router or computer running an STP service); if it's a legitimate device, change it to use a higher priority value; and if it's not, figure out who put it on your network.

The line "CST Root Port: 2/46" in your STP status tells you where the bad root is connected.)

(Maybe consider enabling features such as "BPDU guard" to prevent certain ports from accepting STP entirely if they're not supposed to have a switch connected, or "restricted role" / "root guard" to prevent them from being elected as root ports while still allowing STP.)

Comment: It turns out they have a new switch witch was configured wrong.. The switch was not in use, so I disabled port 2/26.